# Should I use SignalR for private room chatting in IOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, signalr

this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/) helped me a lot to see how web sockets can work with ios. The author was doing a chat room with mechanism for users to dis/connect. All chatters were using the 3000 port to listen to send/receive messages. 
That is good and dandy, but what if I want to utilize it to make a private chat for 1:1?
Would all my users share the same port or do I have manage the ports!?
Wouldn't it hog and drain the ios when it keeps listening in case a response comes?
Thoughts please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more researching about this found me the answers to these. Actually what controls who listen to what and when is the use of Groups in signalR. Check out this post: [One to one chat using Asp.net SignalR groups](http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2013/02/17/One-to-one-chat-using-Aspnet-SignalR-groups.aspx)